# Creating a new basic container to go inbetween two existing ones

Tags: html, css

Hi I am really struggling to create a new container between these two, I need somewhere to add content to the site and unable to do it ! I want to add to white part:

[image]

If I can just get a HTML to match the layout so its all within the borders it would be great.

Below is the HTML that's in between the area I want to add to.

```html
<li><a href="/Contactus.html" accesskey="5" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="page-wrapper"> </div>
<div id="featured-wrapper"> </div>
<div id="contact" class="container">
  <div class="major">
    <h2>Get in touch</h2>
    <span class="byline">It's easy to contact us as we are always here 
    to help</span>
  </div>
  <ul class="contact">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>
  .container{
   max-width:90%;
   min-height: 700px;
   margin:0 auto;
   padding:0;
  }
  #heading{
   width: inherit;
   min-height: 60px;
   line-height: 59px;
   margin:0 auto;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: blue;
   color:white;
   font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
  }
  #navigation{
   width: inherit;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   background-color: gray;
   color:white;
   min-height: 30px;
   line-height: 29px;
   text-align: center;
  }
  #navigation ul
  {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;

  }
  #navigation ul li{
   display:inline;
   padding-right: 30px;
   margin:0 auto;
  }
  #navigation ul li a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color:white;
  }
  #navigation ul li a:hover{
   color:gray;
  }
  .panel{
   width: inherit;
   margin:0 auto;
   height: 200px;
   color:white;
   background-color: black;
   text-align: center;
   border:1px solid black;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #heading{
     width: 100%;
    }
    #navigation{
     width: 100%;

    }
    #navigation ul
    {
     margin:0 auto;
    }
    #navigation ul li {
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
  }
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
  <div id="heading">
   <h1>Connection Wellbeing Services</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="navigation">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">HOME PAGE</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">OUR CLIENTS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
   <h2>Get in touch</h2>
  </div>
 </div>




</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if this is what you asked for, it's basically another div in between that you can use to fill that white space with some content